# React unit tests for dropdown

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing

I am writing unit tests for a dropdown menu in my application. While I was able to compose unit tests for simple HTML elements, such as:

I face more complexity when working on unit tests for components that depend on incoming data. A key example of this complexity exists in the following block of my code:

```
{currentUserData ? (
<DropdownButton className='nav-user-dropdown'
size='sm'
align={{ sm: 'end' }}
title={<Avatar user={currentUserData} />}
data-testid='navbar-user-dropdown'>
//... Dropdown contents here
</DropdownButton>) : (<LoginButton />)
}
```

This part of the code relies on the currentUserData object, which is received from a user context. The expected output, of course, is a pass for the unit test.

Even though simpler tests, such as checking for the presence of a navbar, pass without an issue:

```
describe('Test Navbar and functions', () => {
test('Nav should contain nav-bar', async () => {
render(
<Router>
<NavBar
handleLogin={function (): void {
throw new Error('Function not implemented.')
}}
handleLogout={function (): void {
throw new Error('Function not implemented.')
}}
/>
</Router>
)
expect(screen.getByTestId('nav-bar')).toBeInTheDocument()
})
}
```

I primarily struggle with writing unit tests that involve the currentUserData object. My partial solution to this problem currently involves mocking the useContext function to simulate receiving the currentUserData object. Here's one of the failed tests:

```
`jest.spyOn(React, 'useContext').mockImplementation(() => ({`
`currentUserData = {...},`
`setCurrentUserData: jest.fn(),`
`isLoading: false,`
`}))`
```

While running my tests, I encountered the following recurring error:

FAIL  src/components/globals/modules/**tests**/NavBar.test.tsx (9.3 s)
● Test Navbar and functions › Nav should render with current user data
You cannot render a <Router> inside another <Router>. You should never have more than one in your app.
This error refers to a Router that I implemented in my tests. Any help on how to resolve this problem would be tremendously helpful.

For further context, here is the currentUserData object and its structure:
javascript const currentUserData = { id: 'l3', b2cOid: '', loginEmail: '', firstName: '', lastName: '', timeZoneOffSet: '', timeZone: '', isAdmin: , userRoles: [ '' ], avatarUrl: '', thumbnailPhoto: [ 255, 216, 255, 219 ], isClient: false, createdAt: '', updatedAt: '', notificationEnabled: , notificationFrequency: '', contactId: '', // Additional properties... }

And this is how currentUserData is used in my component:
const NavBar = ({ handleLogin, handleLogout }: NavBarProps) => {
const { currentUserData } = useContext(UserContext)

```
  let isClient = true
  if (currentUserData?.isClient !== undefined) {
    isClient = currentUserData.isClient
  }

  let formattedLastLogIn = ''
  const options: Intl.DateTimeFormatOptions = {
  }

  const lastUserLogIn = currentUserData?.lastUserLogIn

  if (lastUserLogIn != null && lastUserLogIn != undefined) {
    const loginDate = new Date(lastUserLogIn)
    formattedLastLogIn = loginDate.toLocaleString('en-GB', options).replace(',', '')
  }
```

If anyone is familiar with the Jest framework, I would appreciate your guidance on how to properly test components that depend on incoming data from contexts. Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.